# Pandas duplicate columns with a shift

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` time series object with 3 series and a time axis. I want to train a neural network with a time window and for that reason I need to create a matrix of duplicated pandas columns with different shifts. I Could do it with `pandas.concat` manually, but that'd take a long time to do and it won't be very flexible. What I'm trying now is:

```
# Make 40 columns with the original dataframe first column and
# make 20 columns with the original dataframe second column
param_array = pandas.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 41) :
  param_array = pandas.concat([param_array, input[[0]].shift(i * 2)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

for i in range(1, 21) :
   param_array= pandas.concat([param_array, input[[1]].shift(i * 2)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

But this just appends the time series at the end of the first one, it doesn't make new columns.

Comment: Quite impossible to understand what your problem is: see [ask]

Comment: There are some ways to append columns to a pandas data frame. One way can be df["new_column"] = ts, where df is a dataframe, and ts is a series object of some kind ( list, numpy array... ).

Comment: boardrider: I believe "create a matrix of duplicated pandas columns" from my original pandas dataset is quite descriptive. If you believe you can word it better please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your reference to 'input[[0]]' is not correct.  I get an example of what you are trying to do with your own code below. The new columns are shifted values of the original data:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one': pd.Series(range(20)),'two':pd.Series(range(20)[::-1])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print df

param_array = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 5) :
  param_array = pd.concat([param_array, df['one'].shift(i * 2)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

for i in range(1, 5) :
  param_array = pd.concat([param_array, df['two'].shift(i * 2)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

print param_array
```

output:

```
   one  two
0     0   19
1     1   18
2     2   17
3     3   16
4     4   15
5     5   14
6     6   13
7     7   12
8     8   11
9     9   10
10   10    9
11   11    8
12   12    7
13   13    6
14   14    5
15   15    4
16   16    3
17   17    2
18   18    1
19   19    0
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2    0 NaN NaN NaN  19 NaN NaN NaN
3    1 NaN NaN NaN  18 NaN NaN NaN
4    2   0 NaN NaN  17  19 NaN NaN
5    3   1 NaN NaN  16  18 NaN NaN
6    4   2   0 NaN  15  17  19 NaN
7    5   3   1 NaN  14  16  18 NaN
8    6   4   2   0  13  15  17  19
9    7   5   3   1  12  14  16  18
10   8   6   4   2  11  13  15  17
11   9   7   5   3  10  12  14  16
12  10   8   6   4   9  11  13  15
13  11   9   7   5   8  10  12  14
14  12  10   8   6   7   9  11  13
15  13  11   9   7   6   8  10  12
16  14  12  10   8   5   7   9  11
17  15  13  11   9   4   6   8  10
18  16  14  12  10   3   5   7   9
19  17  15  13  11   2   4   6   8
```

Comment: If you believe this is a solution to the problem could you please accept the answer?